# $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=5+2\sqrt6$, then $x+y$ is equal to

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Usually, there would be only one value $x$ are asked to find, but here $x+y$ are to be found out.  Help needed.  Find the value of $x+y$,

$\sqrt x+\sqrt y=5+2\sqrt6$, then $x+y$ is equal to ___?

Comment: You can't find $x+y$ with that equation. Is there anything missing? Like $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Well...one solution is $x=25$, $y=24$.  If you don't tell us more about $x,y$, then another solution is $x=(5+2\sqrt 6)^2$, $y=0$.

Comment: Is there any other constraint? Otherwise the answer will not be unique.

Comment: Maybe $x$ and $y$ are required to be integers?

Comment: Are you sure it is not $(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)^2=5+2\sqrt6$

Answer (score 2):

*Rational solutions:*

As we have only positive numbers, the equation is equivalent to
$$x+y+2\sqrt{xy}=49+20\sqrt 6\iff \begin{cases}x+y=49\\xy=600\end{cases}$$
So $x$ and $y$ are the integer roots, if any, of the quadratic equation 
$$t^2-49t+600=0.$$
The discriminant is $1$ and the rational roots are $24$ and $25$.

Answer (score 1):

You may very well see $x+y$ as an unknown, let $s$. Then eliminating $x$, you want to solve

$$\sqrt{s-y}+\sqrt y=5+2\sqrt6,$$

giving

$$x+y=s=(5+2\sqrt6-\sqrt y)^2+y$$ where $y$ is a positive number, which must also fulfills $\sqrt y\le5+2\sqrt6$ to make the first inequation possible.

---

Of course the question doesn't make much sense without the integrality constraint, but my point here is how to deal with a problem where you are not asked for the unknowns themselves.

Comment: How do you find $y$?

Comment: Options available are,                                                                               (a) 2 sqrt(6) (b), 5-2sqrt(6)  (c) 5 (d) 2sqrt(6)

Comment: @YvesDaoust You have $5 + 2 \sqrt 6 - \sqrt y \ge 0$ constraint. Also, you seemingly forgot $2$ in the last expression.

Comment: @Abstraction: oooops, quite right. Fixing.

Comment: @Bernard: in the absense of other constraint, any $0\le y\le(5+2\sqrt6)^2$ is valid.

Comment: @Raman It's just me or options (a) and (d) are the same? And it seems that **Shailesh** was right in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 5 + 2\sqrt{6}$.

Squaring both the sides, we get
$$x + y + 2\sqrt{xy} = 25 + 24 + 2\sqrt{25\cdot24}$$
Now if you observe closely and compare, we get $x = 25$ and $y = 24$.
Please correct me if I am wrong; this is my first answer here.

Comment: To typeset mathematical expressions, enclose them in dollar signs (so `$x$` gives $x$). You will find much more information in this [nice tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Welcome to MathSE.